# How do I get the logged in user's window's credentials in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, wcf-security

I have a little application I build that monitors tickets submitted.  It basically just sits there in the corner and notifies when new tickets arrive.  I need to get the persons username who is logged into the computer to pull their tickets.

I tried searching, but I think I'm using the wrong terminology as I couldn't really find anything.

Comment: You have a WPF application that depends on the user's credentials to alert when a ticket is received?

Comment: Sure, it's got a timer so every so often it checks the database for new tickets.

Comment: The solutions below from @SLaks and @"Jouke van der Maas" work well to get the username that launched the executing process, which isn't necessarily the same as the logged in (or interactive) user (e.g., a system service). If you need the latter, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218778/how-to-get-currently-logged-username-from-windows-service-in-net).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Environment.UserName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx).

You may also be looking for the [`Environment.UserDomainName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Try `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`

Comment: This worked, but the Environment.Username worked a little better as I didn't have to strip out the domain.

Comment: Fair enough, i forgot what that was and was to lazy too look it up. I just googled and found this.