# How do I get the currently-logged username from a Windows service in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-identity

I have a Windows service which needs the currently logged username. I tried `System.Environment.UserName`, Windows identity and Windows form authentication, but all are returning "**System**" as the user my service is running as has system privileges. Is there a way to get the currently logged in username without changing my service account type?

Comment: Are you aware that there may be more than one logged on user? Do you want them all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442488/c-net-getting-user-name-of-machine-using-windows-service and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727393/get-user-sid-from-logon-id-windows-xp-and-up
I think you can also get the logged users by reading the windows registry (those with SID subkey).

Comment: ya of course, all logged user.

Comment: Related: *[How do I get the current username in .NET using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373)*

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This is a [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) query to get the user name:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```

You will need to add `System.Management` under References manually.

Comment: People keep forgetting that the usual ways to "get" a username wont work when running a service because of the System Accounts... +1 for being the only answer to take this into account

Comment: I realize this question is really old, but I found it while Googling the same issue. While this answer is indeed correct, keep in mind, as @xanblax said in his answer, this WMI query will not work in a remote (RDP) session. Just wanted to point that out, and make it more visible, in case anyone else reads this in the future.

Comment: Old answers are still useful. I stumbled across this _now_, August 2018.

Comment: @Tapas Can u suggest how it can be used for a standard user?

Comment: Works fine in my service application running under a system account in Windows 10 20H2. Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

If you are in a network of users, then the username will be different:

```
Environment.UserName
```

Will Display format : 'Username',
rather than

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

Will Display format : 'NetworkName\Username'

Choose the format you want.

Comment: just what i was looking for !

Comment: That totally doesn't answer the question.  When your application is running as a service, both of those calls will return the service account name.

Comment: it will return current service user, not user

Answer (score 22):

ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem") solution worked fine for me. BUT it does not work if the service is started over a Remote Desktop Connection.
To work around this, we can ask for the username of the owner of an interactive process that always is running on a PC: explorer.exe. This way, we always get the currently Windows logged-in username from our Windows service:

```
foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject Process in Processes.Get())
{
    if (Process["ExecutablePath"] != null && 
        System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Process["ExecutablePath"].ToString()).ToLower() == "explorer.exe" )
    {
        string[] OwnerInfo = new string[2];
        Process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", (object[])OwnerInfo);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Windows Logged-in Interactive UserName={0}", OwnerInfo[0]));

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use this answer, but I couldn't find the class Processes.

Comment: This doesn't work if multiple users are logged in at once (e.g. in Windows 10 when you switch to another user) as one instance of explorer.exe is running for each user.

Comment: It should be the following: 

ManagementObjectSearcher Processes =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");

Comment: to make sure I was getting the correct copy of explorer.exe, I got the current process and took the session ID from that, then I compared that to the SessionID property value from the explorer.exe I found and then got the user information from that one.

Comment: Of course a Windows Service might be in a session without a UI or without explorer.exe running in it's session, so you might have to doing some other way, but I am using this in a windows desktop application and it is working great.

Answer (score 6):

Modified code of [Tapas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218778/how-do-i-get-the-currently-logged-username-from-a-windows-service-in-net/7186755#7186755):

```
Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
Dim collection As ManagementObjectCollection = searcher.[Get]()
Dim username As String
For Each oReturn As ManagementObject In collection
    username = oReturn("UserName")
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is looking for user ***Display Name*** as opposed to ***User Name***, like me.

Here's the treat :

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName.

Add Reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` in your project.

Comment: When I try this, I get the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'."

Answer (score 1):

Try `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`. You need to add reference to `System.Security.Principal`

Comment: I think this will return the user that the service is running as, not all interactive users as seen from the service running under a system account.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserName");
```

Comment: What will that display? Domain\Username or just Username?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: It just returns Username - It is equivalent of using the property 'Environment.UserName'

Answer (score 0):

Completing the answer from @xanblax

```
private static string getUserName()
{
    SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery(@"Select * from Win32_Process");
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    {
       foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject Process in searcher.Get())
        {
            if (Process["ExecutablePath"] != null && string.Equals(Path.GetFileName(Process["ExecutablePath"].ToString()), "explorer.exe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                string[] OwnerInfo = new string[2];
                Process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", (object[])OwnerInfo);
                 return OwnerInfo[0];
            }
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer for Windows Service:

You can get it from the `sessionId` of a currently logged-in user. First, you have to add following `P/INVOKE` script in your code class:

```
[DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
private static extern bool WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, WtsInfoClass wtsInfoClass, out IntPtr ppBuffer, out int pBytesReturned);
[DllImport("Wtsapi32.dll")]
private static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pointer);
 
private enum WtsInfoClass
{
    WTSUserName = 5, 
    WTSDomainName = 7,
}

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
```

Then, add this method:

```
private static string GetUsername(int sessionId, bool prependDomain = true)
{
    IntPtr buffer;
    int strLen;
    string username = "SYSTEM";
    if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, sessionId, WtsInfoClass.WTSUserName, out buffer, out strLen) && strLen > 1)
    {
        username = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer);
        WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
        if (prependDomain)
        {
            if (WTSQuerySessionInformation(IntPtr.Zero, sessionId, WtsInfoClass.WTSDomainName, out buffer, out strLen) && strLen > 1)
            {
                username = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(buffer) + "\\" + username;
                WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
    return username;
}
```

Finally, call the method like this:

```
int sessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
string username = GetUsername(sessionId); // Gives 'Domain\Username'
```

Source links:

- https://codedrum.blogspot.com/2016/03/c-how-to-get-logged-in-users-username.html
- https://smbadiwe.github.io/post/track-activities-windows-service/