# How to get logged in user from a service in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am developing a C# windows service.

I need to know (from the service) who is the currently logged on user.

I tried to follow the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218778/how-to-get-currently-logged-username-from-windows-service-in-net) with this code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```

But the problem is that it works only on Windows 7, but on Windows 8 I get an empty string.

Was the WMI changed in Windows 8?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the overall contents of `searcher` ? I suspect it has something to do with logging in through a Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with windows 8 but the fact that I used remote connection.
This WMI doesn't work for remote connection.