# how to find the user name of the system logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want the user name of the that id from which user is logged in system.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal p = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal as System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal;
string strName = p.Identity.Name;
```

I have written above code but not getting the user name but it is giving the alias name

Comment: Could you give an example? (I assume you logged in to an AD.)

Comment: look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218778/how-to-get-currently-logged-username-from-windows-service-in-net

Comment: i am doing this then i am getting alias name(e.g. spidy_007@outtlook.com) but i want the name of the user of this account(user name : Ramandeep Singh)

Answer (score 2):

```
var username = Environment.UserName
```

Answer (score 1):

`string strName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;`