# Get Windows user C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that needs to get the Windows username of the user. I am using the following line of code:

`MessageBox.Show("Your username is:\n" + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);`

This works fine on my computer and computers of our other developers, but for others, it crashes. I'm assuming this is a permissions issue. Here is the error:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01: notesformultipleproperties.exe
Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03: 51cb04a1
Problem Signature 04: PresentationFramework
Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06: 504dc7da
Problem Signature 07: 7b4d
Problem Signature 08: 0
Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID: 1033
Additional Information 1: 0a9e
Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3: 0a9e
Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Can I allow this line of code to run no matter what permissions the user has?

Comment: Do you just need the user name alone, or will you also need domain information?  `Environment.UserName` will _not_ provide the domain, while your current method will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `Environment.UserName`? It will return "the user name the current process is running under".

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Environment.UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx) instead of getting the `WindowsIdentity`.  This requires fewer permissions, and will likely work without the elevated permissions you're currently requiring.

Answer (score 2):

This question has an accepted answer: [How do I get the logged in user's window's credentials in a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885637/how-do-i-get-the-logged-in-users-windows-credentials-in-a-wpf-application)

[`Environment.UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx)

Comment: Then why post another one?

Comment: Because I didn't have enough reputation at the time to mark as a duplicate or comment on the original post :)

Comment: nevertheless, this is not an answer. flagged.

Comment: How is it not an answer? It provides the same answer as the other two answers (including the accepted one)? I just acknowledge the existence of another question with the same answer.

Comment: They're right. You should have left it in the comments of the original question.

Comment: As I mentioned originally, I didn't have enough reputation to do so when I posted this answer. If I did have the reputation at the time, I certainly would have done that. Ironically, this answer has bumped me over 50 reputation so now I can.