# Will Environment.UserName return the same result in Windows 7, Windows 8.x and Windows 10?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I need to get the logged in user's name in a WPF application I'm working on. I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885637/how-do-i-get-the-logged-in-users-windows-credentials-in-a-wpf-application) for a few years back. But now I'm wondering about the Environment.UserName command; will it return the same result whether or not it runs on a Windows 7, Windows 8.x or Windows 10 machine?

Comment: I thought it did. Just got a user emailing me, because the Environment.UserName is returning the text '%username%' instead of 'Bob'

Comment: I think it may do with not being a 'local' account. There are some other stackoverflows on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394019/get-username-in-a-windows-10-c-sharp-uwp-universal-windows-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), yes it will.