# Get UserName in a Windows 10 C# UWP Universal Windows app

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

I am struggling with yet another simple task in the Windows 10 UWP world.

I simply need the UserName of the current Windows user. Environment.UserName is just not a thing in UWP. And no amount of searching the web has helped so far. Hence my post here.

Anyone? Is this just not possible now?

Comment: can you use pinvoke? see here http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.getusername

Comment: Your google-fu needs work young grasshopper: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03fce2c7-225e-40fe-ae7a-8dcef6c8f340/uwpcget-current-username?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Yes, pinvoke works. Looking at other answers below now too. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Yes, found that page first. Didn't help me I'm afraid. The pinvoke method worked first time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Add **"User Account Information"** capability to your app in the Package.appxmanifest

[image: Package.appxmanifest, User Account Information]

2. Use this code to get user display name:

   ```
   private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync();

       var current = users.Where(p => p.AuthenticationStatus == UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated && 
                                   p.Type == UserType.LocalUser).FirstOrDefault();

       // user may have username
       var data = await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
       string displayName = (string)data;

       //or may be authinticated using hotmail 
       if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
       {

           string a = (string)await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.FirstName);
           string b = (string)await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.LastName);
           displayName = string.Format("{0} {1}", a, b);
       }

       text1.Text = displayName;
   }
   ```

Comment: Jeez. That's a lot of work just to get the username.

Comment: Maladeț Sireoja, merge codu'

Comment: I'm unclear about this answer. Nothing in this code restricts to the current user. Rather, it loads ALL local users in the system that may be logged in, and then just shows the first one. Windows does allow more than one user at a time (ie: fast user switching, terminal services, other situations). I don't see anything here to guarantee the correct user for those situations.

Comment: Hello, I also need to get the current user in my UWP app, but I would get the same result "couple" that the command line "whoami" (domain\name).
Is it possible? I'm based on the code given by @Sergiu Cojocaru and on the official sample on UserInfo, but it doesn't seem possible...
I've asked the question in another topic if you need more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179695/uwp-get-the-current-username-to-provide-rights-to-the-user

Comment: What does **Add "User Account Information" capability to your app** mean and how would you do that?

Comment: Adding to @slayernoah 's comment. In your **Package.appxmanifest** make sure you add `<uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation" />` between `<Capabilities> </Capabilities>`. This is for windows 10 apps you **must** have this added. But once that is added the above code (Sergui's code) will work just fine.

Comment: ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path might have what you're looking for, good enough to parse out the username for my purposes....

Answer (score 7):

```
// get username
public string UserNameStr { get; set; } = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

This will get you the full domain\username.

Answer (score 5):

As I can see, there is a `User` class available (UWP): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.user.aspx

Try this:

```
var users = await User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser);
var name = await users.FirstOrDefault().GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
```

Comment: Thank you but no good. The var name =... exits straight away and ends further processing on the lines after.

Comment: I didn't test it, but [HERE](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserInfo) is an official sample from Microsoft. Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe Marcinax's answer might work. The User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser) returns null and therefore the next line of code blows up (async so just exits). Is there something in the Capabilities in the Package.appxmanifest that needs a tick?

Comment: The user must provide consent to obtain this information, the manifest must contain the uap:userAccountInformation capability.

Comment: that kept stucking at GetPropertyAsyc when i tried using it.

`var users = User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser).AsTask().Result;
            var name = users.FirstOrDefault().GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName).AsTask().Result.ToString();
            return name;`

worked for me.

Comment: User.FindAllAsync(UserType) is obsolete: 'FindAllAsyncByType is deprecated and might not function consistently on all platforms. Instead, use FindAllAsync or GetDefault.'

Answer (score 2):

You can also pickup the User who launched the app from the [Application.OnLaunched](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched.aspx) method see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.launchactivatedeventargs.user.aspx).

You still need to declare the User Information capability in you manifest though.

quick example (Ellipses denote non applicable generated code):

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    ... 
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        User currentUser = e.User;
        ... 
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Bah, the incoming user is null.