# How to get all Microsoft administrator account information on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows-10, admin, microsoft-account

Is there a way to get all Microsoft accounts and the admin user in them?

1. Get all local admin user by `win32_UserAccount`, if it's Microsoft account, we cant get related info, such as email info.
2. `WindowsIdentity.Getcurrent()` can get current user, and if it is Microsoft account, it can get email info.

Comment: IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync();  [Get UserName in a Windows 10 C# UWP Universal Windows app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394019/get-username-in-a-windows-10-c-sharp-uwp-universal-windows-app) use it, it seems only get one user info.

Answer (score 0):

HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\StoredIdentities
The RegistryKey will list the email and local user's sid, you can get local infomation by sid.